# Unable to add service principle, groups to the $logs container in ADLS2

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

Recently enabled storage analytics on ADLS Gen2 storage account.I can see the $logs container and the logs are writing to this on an hourly basis. But when I'm trying to add service principal to this container getting permission denied. I have storage data contributor role on this storage account, any special permission is required to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In general, being able to manage IAM requires higher level roles to be granted to your account. I assume, that you're trying to grant access via **Access Control (IAM)** feature / API call. Using Storage Data Contributor is not sufficient as it only allows you to access containers and blobs with read / write / delete access.

You need a role which grants you `Microsoft.Authorization/*/write` permission in order to get it working.

Comment: I'm able to successfully add SP's to other containers from storage explorer but not to $logs.

Comment: @praneethh I will have to replay that scenario and will come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved by adding the SP/groups from the portal at the container level instead of storage explorer.